# Looping through json object that has an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

**What I'm trying to output with JS**:

```
<ul>
  <li>title1
    <ul>
      <li>image1</li>
      <li>image2</li>
      <li>image3</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>title2
    <ul>
      <li>image1</li>
      <li>image2</li>
      <li>image3</li>
   </ul>
  </li>

...and so forth...

</ul>
```

**JSON:**

```
var data = [
    {
        title: "title1", 
        image:["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    },
    {
        title: "title2", 
        image:["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    },
    {
        title: "title3", 
        image:["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    },
    {
        title: "title4", 
        image:["image1", "image2", "image3"]
    }
];
```

**My JS**

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  var obj = {
      title:item.title,
      image:item.image
  };
  var theimages;
  var html = '';

    for(j=0; j < item.image.length; j++) {
         theimages = '<li>' + item.image[j] + '</li>'; 
    }

html += '<li>' + item.title + '<ul>';
html += theimages;
html += '</ul></li>';
} 
console.log(html);
```

Can someone explain how do I get the value of the inner `for` `loop` and combine it with the outer `for` `loop` so that I end up with output I'm trying to achieve. currently I end up with this:

```
<li>title4
  <ul>
    <li>image3</li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Inside your `for` loop, you should use `+=` as in `theimages += ...` so it always adds to the end of the string, instead of replacing it.

Comment: You are overwriting the images variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you overwrite the *html* variable in every iteration of the outer for-loop.

If you declare this variable before the loop, you get the right result. Also you don't want to overwrite the *theimages* variable everytimes, but append the new portion to it.

```
var html = '';
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  var theimages = '';
  for(j=0; j < item.image.length; j++) {
    theimages += '<li>' + item.image[j] + '</li>'; 
  }

  html += '<li>' + item.title + '<ul>';
  html += theimages;
  html += '</ul></li>';
} 
console.log(html);
```

Also I have removed your obj-variable, since you did not use it anyway.

Just use this pattern, if you build strings:
    var myString = ''
    for(item ...) {
      myString += item
    }
At first initialize the string, then append.

Comment: Awesome...that worked. Was very frustrating seeing how I close I was. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

You just need to append it to the string, instead of reassigning the variable again and again:

```
var theimages;
var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var item = data[i];
  var obj = {
      title:item.title,
      image:item.image
  };


for(j=0; j < item.image.length; j++) {
         theimages += '<li>' + item.image[j] + '</li>'; 
    }

html += '<li>' + item.title + '<ul>';
html += theimages;
html += '</ul></li>';
}  
html += '</ul>';
console.log(html);
```

Comment: I get undefined after the ul and the inner loop looks to be incrementing by the outer forloop index...
<ul>
  <li>title1
    <ul>undefined
      <li>image1</li>
      <li>image2</li>
      <li>image3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>title2
    <ul>undefined
      <li>image1</li>
      <li>image2</li>
      <li>image3</li>
      <li>image1</li>
      <li>image2</li>
      <li>image3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  ....and so forth....
</ul>